# How Can I Record Microphone And Speakers Audio at Same Time in C#?

Tags: c#, naudio

I am trying make program for record my microphone and all things I hear at same time.

I tried use `WasapiLoopbackCapture` work perfect but don't get microphone and `waveIn` record only microphone.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to record both the capture and render devices separately with `WasapiCapture` and `WasapiLoopbackCapture` and then mix the two together manually.